# Cloning a type and using it's keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I know this sounds like a Frankenstein's monster idea, but hear me out. I have a type:

```
export enum detailsDataTypes {
  MACHINE = 'MACHINE',
  USER = 'USER',
  ABSTRACT = 'ABSTRACT',
}

export type sharedTypes = {
  name?: string;
  OEECategory?: string;
  OAECategory?: string;
  color?: string;
};

export type AbstractData = sharedTypes & {
  layer: string;
  type: detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT;
};

export type UserData = sharedTypes & {
  defaultTimeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverwrite: string;
  type: detailsDataTypes.USER;
};

export type MachineData = Omit<UserData, 'type'> & {
  stateCategory: string;
  canOverwriteOnlyByStates: boolean;
  machineType: string;
  type: detailsDataTypes.MACHINE;
};
```

And this type is good for containing data. But I want another type to be holding headers (human readable). This is my idea:

```
const sharedHeaders: sharedTypes = {
  name: 'Name',
  OEECategory: 'OEE category',
  OAECategory: 'OAE category',
  color: 'Color',
};

export const AbstractHeaders: Omit<AbstractData, 'type'> = { ...sharedHeaders, layer: 'Layer' };

export const UserHeaders: Omit<UserData, 'type'> | { defaultTimeout: string } = {
  ...sharedHeaders,
  defaultTimeout: 'Default timeout',
  stateAfterTimeout: 'State after timeout',
  accessCanChoose: 'Access - can choose',
  accessCanOverwrite: 'Access - can overwrite',
};

export const MachineHeaders: Omit<MachineData, 'type'> = {
  ...UserHeaders,
  stateCategory: 'State category',
  machineType: 'Machine type',
  canOverwriteOnlyByStates: 'Can overwrite only by states',
};
```

But here we have a bunch of type conflicts, and I can't help but think there has to be a better way to do this.

For example here, I get that all after the destructuring are string, which is not assignable to type never.

```
export const MachineHeaders: Omit<MachineData, 'type'> = {
  ...UserHeaders,
  stateCategory: 'State category', //here
  machineType: 'Machine type', //here
  canOverwriteOnlyByStates: 'Can overwrite only by states', //here
};
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Or am I thinking about it in the wrong way?

Comment: I'm confused about what `MachineData` is supposed to be.  Is it intentional that `type MachineData = UserData & ...` instead of `type MachineData = sharedTypes & ...`?  If so, can you explain it?  If not, is this whole question just the result of a typo or is something else going on?

Comment: Essentially `UserData` is `sharedData` + additional properties, and `MachineData` is `UserData` + additional properties.

Comment: Hmm, but one of your "additional" properties is `type`, which conflicts with the `type` from `UserData`; it's impossible for `type` to be two different string literals at the same time, so the compiler reduces the whole thing to `never`...  would [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzoQ3w) work for you instead?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, this is almost perfect. I tried to deal with casting `canOverwriteOnlyByStates` to string like you did with `defaultTimeout` but couldn't get it to work. Can you elaborate? + why does this work, and what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: I'm not casting anything with `defaultTimeout`... but now I see that you're using a union instead of an intersection, so... uh... is your intent that you want every property to be a `string`?  You've essentially got two unrelated issues then.  One is that you were defining `MachineData` to be `never`; I've fixed that.  Now you are trying to map properties to `string`.  I can fix that too, but these really are two separate issues that should be two separate questions.  Which one do you want solved here?  Edit one out of the question and I'll answer what remains.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx5qKW) is how I'd approach making a `HeadersFor<T>` type that omits `type` from `T`'s properties and maps everything else to `string`.  Personally I feel like this is the more interesting question and the `type MachineData = UserData &` to `type MachineData = Omit<UserData, "type"> &` change should just be made to your original question so it doesn't have to be answered... but it's your question, not mine.  Let me know.

Comment: This question is more about the mapping all types to string. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure, if you edit the code in the question to define `MachineData` so that it is not `never`.

Comment: Edited. Should be ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an object type and would like to programmatically create a new object type from it, you can often use [a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to do it.

---

In your case, you have a bunch of object types whose property value types are arbitrary, and you'd like to come up with new versions with the same keys  but whose properties are all `string`, to use as headers for a table of values or something.

We can do that this way:

```
type HeadersFor<T> = { [K in keyof T]: string };
```

Let's test it out:

```
type X = HeadersFor<{ a: number, b: boolean, c?: Date, type: string }>;
/* type X = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c?: string | undefined;
  type: string;
} */
```

As you see, each property has been transformed to `string`.  Well, the `c` field was [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) in the input type and it remains so in the output type (and therefore includes `undefined` as a possibility).  If you'd like the output properties to be required and not optional, you can use a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to achieve that:

```
type HeadersFor<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: string };

type X = HeadersFor<{ a: number, b: boolean, c?: Date, type: string }>;
/* type X = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string
  type: string;
} */
```

Great!  But looking at your original, it seems you also want to omit the `type` property entirely.  You can compose `Omit` and `HeadersFor` if you want, or you could redefine `HeadersFor` to automatically exclude a `type` key from the mapped type. There are multiple ways to do that, but since TS4.1 I'd probably recommend using [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) like this:

```
  type HeadersFor<T> = { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "type">]-?: string };

  type X = HeadersFor<{ a: number, b: boolean, c?: Date, type: string }>;
  /* type X = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string
  } */
```

That looks like everything you need, so we'll keep that definition of `HeadersFor`.

---

Now you can do this with no errors:

```
const sharedHeaders: HeadersFor<SharedTypes> = {
  name: 'Name',
  OEECategory: 'OEE category',
  OAECategory: 'OAE category',
  color: 'Color',
};

export const AbstractHeaders: HeadersFor<AbstractData> = { ...sharedHeaders, layer: 'Layer' };

export const UserHeaders: HeadersFor<UserData> = {
  ...sharedHeaders,
  defaultTimeout: 'Default timeout',
  stateAfterTimeout: 'State after timeout',
  accessCanChoose: 'Access - can choose',
  accessCanOverwrite: 'Access - can overwrite',
};

export const MachineHeaders: HeadersFor<MachineData> = {
  ...UserHeaders,
  stateCategory: 'State category',
  machineType: 'Machine type',
  canOverwriteOnlyByStates: 'Can overwrite only by states',
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-KFIuAOUQBEoBkoKlwJKIiWmrIIwD9+NQmu1Gy9+MlmGltzl4KeUj4QmVjCiMSIYHmXgA6tAANZEHBVum7RTl2gtrwhrxQiW-bhJmFQIgAMWgRvIDvCcAA2gBpOBpOD14CUCCwuDkAC6XrgQycLH7kwAGlpBzhh2OJ-Q4DgsWhcVBLdM4wmk4hLR1yktgJbs-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-alrMpPMiz3BDcBPMLRC-YE-2WvshxU+IAAyBxHOI70jK48DM-AppHBzgOXilE6a+aAs2SwwtPKLazi0DCgsIRCJImSwDopiEhYPCiLjKijsYljLokkSJJQA7TvQ1GRR3sSRzuJ7TtY9yRAMn6zKsuyEjsB0dLx3AEno1lHQsmywCx+nPJ+gGUDCoa5GWMXmfZ76WUQAK5dBvTKqM2rEBffArBpogwDa1zE493n2qAhDiimwbEuKL7wB4x6IfRl4JP42T1twKmI99xmEjD1qfeeeTpdNxXJIhmGEahzG0OMnAjeBpXd+hpQfUv7PRD00AA)

Comment: Ok, this works and is amazing, thank you. You sir are a TS wizard. Can you just explain the `: string` part in `{ [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "type">]-?: string };`? That's the one thing I can't find in the docs. I'm assuming this is what "casts" all types to string, but what's the syntax and how does it work exactly?

Comment: In the documentation for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)  it shows how a `{[K in XXX]: boolean}` causes the output property value type to be `boolean` for all keys.  The syntax is hopefully explained there for you.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thanks!